# Send additional variables to page response in Django CMS

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I'm using Django CMS and am trying to figure out how to extend a view for a CMS page. For example, let's say I created a page called "About" in the CMS (/about) that is using the about_template.html file. Before I render the template I'd like to be able to send
additional variables to the response. How do I overwrite the view to send these additional variables to the about page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done by adding variable to the context, like you can see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial03/#write-views-that-actually-do-something). A context is a simple dictionary, you just need to add some key-value in it so your template can read them.

```
context = {'books': Books.objets.all()}
```

You can also use [class-based view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/), but you may want to learn the simple view before.

Comment: Silly me, I forgot there was a render method in the cms_plugins.py where you set the context.